# Outlook Web Access Mobile Options

Tags: webmail, microsoft-office

[image]

Above are screen shots of Outlook Web Access options for two different users, why is that one user has Mobile Devices option enabled and other does not. Both users access same Web Mail.

Is it just that it has been disabled for one user and still active for other.

Thanks

Comment: Are they using the same browser? IIRC OWA displays different sets of options for different browsers

Comment: Same browser different tabs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extra tab reflects the user mobile device if he has configured a mobile device to use with his Mailbox this tab will appear.
inside exchange management you can take a look by right clicking on the user mailbox --> manage mobile devices and there you should see 1 user has a mobile device present and the other user does not .

Comment: i did check with the other user and he does not have any mobile devices configured.. and i would not be able to check exchange management as i am not a admin, i am simply a user. Here is the screen shot of the devices option : [Mobile Devices Option](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UdCAZ.jpg)